# When measuring IR for temperature of shiny surfaces, how is the object own emission added to the reflection?

Tags: reflection, thermal-radiation, glass

While discussing [measuring temperature of a heated glass plate used in 3D printers](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/18791/2338), it was pointed out that IR thermometers are not accurate because, for uncoated and shiny glass surface, they measure the reflection of object around it.

I experienced the effect once when using a IR camera with a mirror and it was interesting, but in this case the heated glass bed is at least 40 °C above room temperature, therefore I would expect the emission from the glass itself (emissivity coefficient quite good, 0.85-0.95) to trump the reflection (IR emission likely goes with the difference of the fourth power of T).

In fact, when I measured my glass plate with an IR thermometer, pointed perpendicular to it, I got a realistic reading, within 1 °C (the calibration of thermistor and thermometer may account for the difference).

Maybe at an angle the behaviour is different?

So how do the emission from the material itself and the reflection combine for glass surfaces, when the measurement angle is changed from 90° to 0°?

Comment: minor note, it's not the fourth power of delta T, it's just the fourth power of T - the absolute temperature in Kelvin

Comment: Please use mathematical symbols as opposed to e.g., delta T, i.e., delta T$\rightarrow \Delta T$.

Comment: Corrected, thanks to both

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact answer, but here is an *engineering trick* used only by real hip dudes which will be helpful.

IR noncontact thermometers assume a certain typical average emissivity for all ordinary objects. you can easily take out the emissivity effect just by calibrating it using a chunk of the actual material, raised to a known temperature.